# Why doesn't this sfdisk script work?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bash, partitioning

I bring greetings from StackOverflow! :D

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109790/bash-how-do-i-use-sfdisk

This has been a painful process. Perhaps there's something simple I'm missing..?

I'm trying to create a script to automatically partition a disk with a gpt table and 1 partition that takes up all the space. Should be super simple and straight forward..

I found the `sfdisk` command which is the (supposedly) script-friendly version of `fdisk`.

The best I've got so far is:

```
sfdisk --color=always --wipe always --no-reread --no-act --label gpt /dev/sdc
```

There's the matter of the partition type, which is to be `Linux Filesystem` (is that a good choice for a data drive?). The GUID for that is `0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4`

When I run the above command, I get an interactive prompt. This is a bit of a problem for my script ;)

What of the input/output format described in the man pages?

`<name>: <value>, <name>: <value>, ...`

It seems to be suggesting I do something like:

```
echo 'label: gpt' | --color=always --wipe always --no-reread --no-act /dev/sdc
```

but, alas, that fails harder than the above: :(

```
Partitioning /dev/sdc...

Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

>>> line 1: unsupported command

New situation: Leaving.
```

Then there's the dumpfile I caught wind of in the depths of the man pages. It seems to suggest that I can create these cursed things, cat them, and pipe to sfdisk. (Un?)fortunately, I can't hardcode most of this so the solution won't work for me:

```
label: gpt
label-id: 236AEC41-D407-4FE5-94FA-8550C2CA10B5
device: /dev/sdc
unit: sectors
first-lba: 2048
last-lba: 5860533134

/dev/sdc1 : start=        2048, size=  5860531087, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4,uuid=8D7D48B0-8BF5-4383-B0EC-615C0E8AF4B4
```

What am I doing wrong!? Thanks :)

Comment: Your `echo ... | ...` command is incomplete above.  I think it needs to be `echo ... | sudo sfdisk ...`?
If I do that the command works for me, so my best unlikely guess is that you were using a really old verson of sfdisk or something?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way: `sgdisk`

```
sgdisk --clear $blkdev
sgdisk --new=0:0:0 --typecode=0:0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 $blkdev
```